# aio-pika RPC pattern example crashes with: RobustConnection: connection closed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, pika

I'm trying to run RPC with `aio-pika` using it's [RPC Pattern](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/patterns.html#rpc). I ran all as it is in docs just changing AMPQ URL and I have an error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
quart_service_01_1  | future: <Task finished coro=<RobustConnection.reconnect() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aio_pika/robust_connection.py:149> exception=RuntimeError('<RobustConnection: "amqp://dev_user:******@rabbit:5672/tgvhost" 1 channels> connection closed',)>
quart_service_01_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
quart_service_01_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 180, in _step
quart_service_01_1  |     result = coro.send(None)
quart_service_01_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aio_pika/robust_connection.py", line 150, in reconnect
quart_service_01_1  |     await self.connect()
quart_service_01_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aio_pika/robust_connection.py", line 105, in connect
quart_service_01_1  |     raise RuntimeError("{!r} connection closed".format(self))
quart_service_01_1  | RuntimeError: <RobustConnection: "amqp://dev_user:******@rabbit:5672/tgvhost" 1 channels> connection closed
```

and right before that trace it seems like client closes a connection to rabbit:

```
2020-03-20 09:45:23.855 [info] <0.639.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.639.0> (172.30.0.5:40902 -> 172.30.0.3:5672)
rabbit_1            | 2020-03-20 09:45:23.870 [info] <0.639.0> connection <0.639.0> (172.30.0.5:40902 -> 172.30.0.3:5672): user 'dev_user' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'tgvhost'
rabbit_1            | 2020-03-20 09:45:23.917 [info] <0.639.0> closing AMQP connection <0.639.0> (172.30.0.5:40902 -> 172.30.0.3:5672, vhost: 'tgvhost', user: 'dev_user')
```

If I try RPC implementation from [Rabbit MQ aio-pika tutorial](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rabbitmq-tutorial/6-rpc.html) everything works fine. I'm not sure if it is a bug or some misconfiguration from my side but I used this rabbit setup with pika (not aio) and nameko framework and had no problems. No I want to migrate to async quart framework and so I need to have RPC with aio-pika.

Docker
RabbitMQ 3.7.5
aio-pika 6.6.0
Python 3.6

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: For some reason my answer was deleted from here 0_o But it was solved by that PR: https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika/pull/308

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something on aio-pika side, I've solved a similar issue by downgrading aio-pika to 6.3.0